# Incorrect reputation count on mobile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, mobile-web

I've been a member of Stack Overflow for about 6 months and since I hit 1.5k, my rep count has always been "2k" on the mobile site. I use Chrome on a 'droid (naturally). Even now that my rep on Stack Overflow has gotten to 2k and on The Workplace I'm just 1.6k, both count as "2k" on the mobile version of both sites. Bug?

Comment: It is by-design.

Comment: @AnnaLear is there any post/ref. regarding this? I could not find it.

Comment: since its your rep .. is more than 1500(even if its 1505) it show 2k if its less than 1.5k(till 1499) it will show 1k ..

Comment: @NullPointer - Any post/ref.?

Comment: @hims056 i saw related but haven't got now ..

Comment: Where does it show you 2k instead of 1.5k?

Comment: @hims056, what could possibly be the design benefit of reporting an inflated (or deflated) figure?

Comment: @kolossus - I don't know why. But where do you see this? In post page, user profile page or any other page.

Comment: @hims056 on my user profile page. Looking at it right now both my SO and WP  accounts read 2k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly based on the clarifications you gave in the comments, this is still by design.

Here is your profile that shows "2k" for both Stack Overflow and the Workplace:

[image]

Here's your profile on the Workplace:

[image]

and on Stack Overflow profile:

[image]

As you can see, rounding is working as expected. This *is* by design because mobile has limited space to work with. Your reputation is not *incorrect*. The individual profiles still show the full, correct amount below your avatar. It is simply displayed in a different, more compact (and admittedly approximated as a result) way on the Accounts list.

Comment: I see nothing! :). But you should understand, 1.6k != 2k. 400 Rep points is quite the approximation (nearest thousand?).

Comment: @kolossus I understand that it's a big step, but I don't see it as a big problem, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I don't think this is by design. I used to use mobile heavily, and I recall that the rep scheme used to be like this:

- If you have <10k: Your full rep is shown
- If you have >=10k: Your rep is shown to the nearest hundreds place, in the form "21.7k"/etc.

In fact, checking on the mobile versions of my accounts on Physics.SE, Chem.SE, and StackApps, I see that there is no rounding for me.

Looks like a bug.